# windows service canStop property

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-services

I created a windows service in c# using Visual Studio 2010. 
I create the service executable in Visual Studio, then start it from nsis installer script. 
I need to set canStop to false but I can't find out how to do that. 
Please advise.

Comment: Just set the CanStop property to false in the constructor.  This is not something you do with the installer.

Comment: ok, sounds good, I just can't find that property.

Comment: I clicked every entry in Solution Explorer and looked at the properties window and CanStop is not listed in any.

Answer (score 3):

Just open the service class in the Designer (double click on the class) and in the property sheet for the class you can set `CanStop` to `false`.

Comment: I can never find that option ... I see GenerateMember, Modifiers, delayedAutoStart, Description, DisplayName, Parent, ServiceName, ServicesDependedOn, StartType

Comment: @xivix: Then set it manually in your code. [Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.canstop.aspx)

Comment: how do I do that ... I tried everything I could find and all I get is visual studio telling me I can only look at the setting but not set it ... I think it has to be set when the service is first created / started

Comment: @xivix: You're looking at the wrong class, you're looking at the installer class, which does have those properties. I'd suggest creating a new empty Service project, then double click the Service1 class file and the property sheet should contain `CanStop`, that might help you locate it in your other project.

Comment: @xivix: Or try doing a search in all your source code for some class inheriting from `ServiceBase`.

Comment: I did a search of all code and canstop was only found in the System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase library ... and the System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController library.  I then clicked Service1.cs properties and all that is listed is Build Action, Copy to Output Directory, Custom Tool, Custom Tool Namespace, File Name, and File Path.  I will now try a new service as you suggested

Comment: I created new service and have the same options in properties for Service1.cs

Comment: oh dear.  I have been single-clicking Service1.cs all this time.  You were right ... I had to double-click ... thank you so much!!!

Comment: oh great ... that worked for STOP but user still has DISABLE option.  So all this was a waste of time ... is there a way to turn off the DISABLE option as well?

Comment: @xivix: Yes, but you do that by not giving the users write access to the services applet, so that they can't change anything. If the users are allowed to administer the services on a machine, then they'll always be able to change things no matter what settings you set in the service itself.

Comment: how would I restrict write access to the services applet?

Comment: @xivix: If they're normal users I'm fairly sure that they by default aren't allowed to do that, but I don't know the exact details. I'd suggest asking at superuser.com or serverfault.com depending on if it's just one machine or for a company network or similar.

Answer (score 0):

you can only get the status using canStop property which is True/False.
It has only a getter method(get) not the setter one.

refer [canStop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.canstop?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) for detail.